# How to use top,gg vote webhook?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, discord.js

I got my bot verified on top.gg and would like to rewards users after they vote for my bot so how do i detect if someone voted for my bot? and get their id and check if itsweekended and do stuff after the vote. Baisically how do i interact with the top.gg vote webhook

Answer (score 1):

Using top,gg webhooks is quite simple you need to make an simple web server with express which uses the top.gg/sdk as a middleware and attach the middleware to the server and then go to https://top.gg/botid/edit then into webhooks scroll down and set the url with the path assuming u have an ip x set the url as x/dblwebhook and set an password of your choice make a new file in your bot folder and put this code in

```
const init = async () => {
  console.log('[EXPRESS] STARTING SERVER')
  const express = require('express')
  const app = express()
  const Topgg = require('@top-gg/sdk')
  // add your top.gg webhook authorization (not bot token)
  const webhook = new Topgg.Webhook('password') 

  app.post('/dblwebhook', webhook.middleware(), (req, res) => {
    // req.vote is your vote object e.g
    console.log(req.vote)
  }) // attach the middleware

  app.listen(25569, () => console.log('SERVER READY'))
}
module.exports.init = init
```

then in your main bot file require it on the the top and call the init function like so

```
const { init } = require('./path-to-server-file')
init()
```

What's happening here is top.gg makes a post request to the url u specified with the details of the vote